# SharePoint - Quickbooks Integration

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-integration

Our client are using Quickbooks accounting software and now they wants to integrate Quickbooks with their SharePoint site.

After googling i found following third party integration tools,

1. Layer2 Business Data List Connector for SharePoint.
2. Cloudpipes.
3. CDATA QuickBooks Cloud Driver.

If anybody having experience of **SharePoint - Quickbooks Integration** OR experience in using above third party tool then please suggest which one is better or should i have to go with any other option?